# Resizing of widgets if we maximize the window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to expand the widget if the window is maximized. Please find the below sample code, if we run this we will get some treeview but if we maximize the window then the treeview will move to left corner, is it possible to get that view expand and fit perfectly after maximized. Thank you

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import datetime
import re
import threading


class Window:
    i=0
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.geometry('700x350+350+100')
        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text='Sample', font=("Arial", 20)).grid(row=0,columnspan=3)
        cols = ('A','B','C')
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self.master, columns=cols)
        v_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.master, orient='vertical', command=self.treeview.yview)
        self.treeview.config( yscrollcommand=v_scrollbar.set)
        for col in cols:
            self.treeview.heading(col, text=col)
            self.treeview.column(col,minwidth=0,width=170)
        
        self.treeview.grid(row=1, column=0)
        v_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nes')
        
        

#--- main---

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try using `pack()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add:

```
self.master.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

to tell the layout manager to expand the cell where the `treeview` is put to fill the available space.

Then add `sticky='nsew'` to `self.treeview.grid(...)`:

```
self.treeview.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

Below is the modified `__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self,master):
    self.master=master
    self.master.geometry('700x350+350+100')
    tk.Label(self.master, text='Sample', font=("Arial", 20)).grid(row=0,columnspan=3)
    cols = ('A','B','C')
    self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self.master, columns=cols)
    v_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.master, orient='vertical', command=self.treeview.yview)
    self.treeview.config( yscrollcommand=v_scrollbar.set)
    for col in cols:
        self.treeview.heading(col, text=col)
        self.treeview.column(col,minwidth=0,width=170)
    
    self.treeview.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew') # added sticky='nsew'
    v_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns')

    # tell layout manager to expand the cell where the treeview is
    self.master.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```